# Trouble with format command changing the value

Tags: string, stata

I first applied `destring` to an ID variable (with 17 digits). They are destrung but then they are shown in scientific notation. So I tried the command `format %20.0f`. Now all digits are shown but the last 2-3 digits are now changed.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eStAY.png)

Answer (score 1):

Stata can only hold numeric variables with up to 16 digits.

Your best option is probably to keep the ID as a string.

The command `format` only affects how a data point is displayed to humans, not how it is actually stored.

Comment: thank you very much. I will just keep it as a string. Just being curious, is it possible that I take the first digit away? Since every ID begins with a "7", it makes no different if the "7" is not there. Then I have only "16"digits to deal with. Would that work?

Comment: Potentially yes, but the true cut off is between 15 and 16 digits, so `9,999,999,999,999,999` cannot be stored either. Numbers with that many digits in Stata starts to behave oddly. And this is an intended trade-off as there is practically no field of science that requires that level of precision. While your IDs could be expressed as a number, you probably never will use it as a number (use it in regressions etc.). Really, use strings to store this ID, or generate a different ID that is much shorter and use that as number if that is your preference.

Answer (score 0):

This is to complement the answer by @TheIceBear.

`format` never changes values. The problem is that your string is too big even for its numeric equivalent to be held exactly in a `double`, except occasionally.

```
clear 
set obs 5
gen id = 17*"9" in 1 
replace id = 16*"9" + "6" in 2 
replace id = 16*"9" + "2" in 3 
replace id = 15*"9" + "88" in 4 
replace id = 15*"9" + "84" in 5 
format id %20s 
destring id, gen(nid)
format nid %20.0f 
list  

     +----------------------------------------+
     |                id                  nid |
     |----------------------------------------|
  1. | 99999999999999999   100000000000000000 |
  2. | 99999999999999996   100000000000000000 |
  3. | 99999999999999992   100000000000000000 |
  4. | 99999999999999988    99999999999999984 |
  5. | 99999999999999984    99999999999999984 |
     +----------------------------------------+
```